# How to select rows based on column value is repeating and has different values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to query a table in order to return rows, but I'm not able to query the table correctly. Here is my table view:

```
Id  Name    Date        Subject     TrackingToken   RegardingObjectId                       Type    TypeName
1   XXXX    8/26/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030062     496BF810-4DBE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/27/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030055     AA8C2F71-CDD1-E311-894A-005056863ADA    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/28/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030055     4DF02C89-2FBE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/29/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030049     496BF810-4DBE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/30/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030049     06393EF9-71CC-E311-894A-005056863ADA    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/31/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030047     8BE51823-52BE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    9/1/2015    RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030003     6ABE11CA-BABF-E311-89E9-005056863ADA    112 RE: YYYY
```

The result set should return:

```
Id  Name    Date        Subject     TrackingToken   RegardingObjectId                       Type    TypeName
1   XXXX    8/27/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030055     AA8C2F71-CDD1-E311-894A-005056863ADA    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/28/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030055     4DF02C89-2FBE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/29/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030049     496BF810-4DBE-E311-9357-00505686395E    112 RE: YYYY
1   XXXX    8/30/2015   RE: XXXXXX  CRM:0030049     06393EF9-71CC-E311-894A-005056863ADA    112 RE: YYYY
```

In other words: Select all records where column TrackingToken is repeating and RegardingObjectId has different value.

Current Query:

```
select [OwnerId],[OwnerIdName],[CreatedOn],[Subject],
[TrackingToken],[RegardingObjectId],
[RegardingObjectTypeCode],[RegardingObjectIdName]

from [TableX].[dbo].[Email] a
where not exists (select [TrackingToken], [RegardingObjectId]
                  from [TableX].[dbo].[Email] b
                  where a.[TrackingToken] = b.[TrackingToken]
                    and a.[RegardingObjectId] = b.[RegardingObjectId]
                    AND RegardingObjectTypeCode = 112
                  group by [TrackingToken],[RegardingObjectId]
                  having count(*)> 1)
  and a.TrackingToken in (select TrackingToken
                          from [TableX].[dbo].[Email]
                          group by TrackingToken
                          having count(*) > 1)
  and a.RegardingObjectId is not null
  and a.RegardingObjectTypeCode = 112
  and a.TrackingToken is not null
order by a.TrackingToken desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the analytic version of COUNT to count records over a certain range (within the TrackingToken in your case). Then only keep those records where the count of different RegardingObjectId is greater than one.

```
select *
from
(
  select mytable.* 
    , count(distinct regardingobjectid) over (partition by trackingtoken) as cnt
  from mytable
) counted
where cnt > 1;
```

EDIT: As Felix Pamittan pointed out, SQL Server doesn't fully support COUNT OVER, such that you cannot use DISTINCT with it. So here is the same with the normal COUNT aggregation:

```
select mytable.* 
from mytable
where 
(
  select count(distinct token.regardingobjectid) 
  from mytable token
  where token.trackingtoken = mytable.trackingtoken
) > 1;
```

Or without a correlated subquery, but a derived table instead:

```
select mytable.* 
from mytable
join
(
  select trackingtoken
  from mytable
  group by trackingtoken
  having count(distinct regardingobjectid) > 1
) tokens on tokens.trackingtoken = mytable.trackingtoken;
```

Comment: Can you do `COUNT(DISTINCT)` on window functions?

Comment: @Felix Pamittan: You are right. Surprisingly SQL Server doesn't support COUNT OVER completely and really lacks counting distinct values. (I usually work with Oracle where COUN(DISTINCT) OVER works perfectly. I had no idea SQL Server might not.)

Comment: Oh, so it works with Oracle. Nice. Anyway, my answer is a work around for `COUNT(DISTINCT) OVER`.

Comment: I've added two solutions with plain aggregation count instead of the analytic COUNT OVER. This could also be used with EXISTS (correlated) or IN (not correlated). So there are many solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the distinct number of [RegardingObjectId]:

```
select TrackingToken
from [TableX].[dbo].[Email]
group by TrackingToken
having count(distinct [RegardingObjectId]) > 1
```

Comment: But he has other columns in the desired result.

Comment: I didn't copy the whole query with the exists and the main select. I just put one of the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

The below is a working example

```
CREATE TABLE #X(Id INT,Name NVARCHAR(8),Date DATE,Subject NVARCHAR(16),TrackingToken NVARCHAR(14),RegardingObjectId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,Type INT,TypeName NVARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO #X(Id,Name,Date,Subject,TrackingToken,RegardingObjectId,Type,TypeName)
VALUES
(1,'XXXX','8/26/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030062','496BF810-4DBE-E311-9357-00505686395E',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','8/27/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030055','AA8C2F71-CDD1-E311-894A-005056863ADA',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','8/28/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030055','4DF02C89-2FBE-E311-9357-00505686395E',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','8/29/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030049','496BF810-4DBE-E311-9357-00505686395E',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','8/30/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030049','06393EF9-71CC-E311-894A-005056863ADA',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','8/31/2015','RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030047','8BE51823-52BE-E311-9357-00505686395E',112,'RE: YYYY'),
(1,'XXXX','9/1/2015' ,'RE: XXXXXX','CRM:0030003','6ABE11CA-BABF-E311-89E9-005056863ADA',112,'RE: YYYY')

SELECT      A.*
FROM        #X AS A
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT      TrackingToken
        FROM        #X
        GROUP BY    TrackingToken
        HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS O ON O.TrackingToken = A.TrackingToken

DROP TABLE #X
```

You can optimize this by adding an index to the TrackingToken column